# PrintDocument: Fit to page

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-3.5, printdocument, pdfium

I am using [PdfiumViewer](https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer) in order to print a PDF file:

```
using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Load(pdfFileName))
{
    using (PrintDocument printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
    {
        printDocument.BeginPrint += PrintDocument_BeginPrint;
        printDocument.EndPrint += PrintDocument_EndPrint;
        printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocument_PrintPage;
        printDocument.QueryPageSettings += PrintDocument_QueryPageSettings;

        printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
        printDocument.Print();
    }
}
```

In my `printDocument` `BeginPrint`, `EndPrint`, `PrintPage` and `QueryPageSettings` events I am not doing anything, only making some logs to a file.

The PDF file is printed but the left and right margins of each page of the document are being cut off so I am trying to fit each PDF document page to the current default selected paper size in the default printer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I have solved the problem by initializing the `CreatePrintDocument` constructor with `PdfPrintMode.ShrinkToMargin`:

```
using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Load(pdfFileName))
{
    using (PrintDocument printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument(PdfPrintMode.ShrinkToMargin))
    {
        printDocument.BeginPrint += PrintDocument_BeginPrint;
        printDocument.EndPrint += PrintDocument_EndPrint;
        printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocument_PrintPage;
        printDocument.QueryPageSettings += PrintDocument_QueryPageSettings;

        printDocument.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
        printDocument.Print();
    }
}
```