# Pdfium stretches or squashes document on printing

Tags: c#, pdfium

I'm using PdfiumViewer in one of my C# applications. This is the part of the code which I'm using for printing:

```
public documentCopies = 2; // here for example's sake, in the app it's set in another part of the code

private void Completed(string newDocName)
{
    short numCopies = 1;

    if (documentCopies > 0)
    {
        numCopies = Convert.ToInt16(documentCopies);
    }

    var path = localDocLocation + "\\" + newDocName;
    string extension = GetExtension(newDocName).ToLower();

    if (extension == "pdf")
    {
        using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(path))
        {
            using (var printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
            {
                // check the current default printer
                System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings settings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
                string defaultPrinterName = settings.PrinterName;

                printDocument.OriginAtMargins = true;
                printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = newDocName;
                printDocument.PrinterSettings.Copies = numCopies;
                printDocument.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
                printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;

                try
                {
                    printDocument.Print();
                } catch (Exception pex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(pex.Message.ToString()));

                    printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = defaultPrinterName;

                    try
                    {
                        printDocument.Print();
                    } catch(Exception pex2)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(pex2.Message.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // do smth else
    }
}
```

PDF documents which are printed are in a format fit for a thermal printer (80mm width), and are created outside of my application, but with that width in mind.

If I print them from, say Adobe Acrobat or Foxit Reader (directly or via CLI), or any other PDF viewer, the print is identical to what I see when viewing the document in the appropriate viewer. You can see the differences in the following image.

[image]

I've tried simplifying the code, and turning it into this, just for testing, but the end results were the same - stretched document in printing.

```
private void Completed(string newDocName)
{
    var path = localDocLocation + "\\" + newDocName;

    using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(path))
    {
        using (var printDocument = document.CreatePrintDocument())
        {
            printDocument.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
            printDocument.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to force shrinking to margin (`document.CreatePrintDocument(PdfiumViewer.PdfPrintMode.ShrinkToMargin)`), as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242333/printdocument-fit-to-page) did not work - the printout was still distorted. Also, if there's more content than in this specific case, the printed content is squashed. The printout's height is just a little bit larger than the document I mentioned in my question.

I'm guessing that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. Should I set the page height to some value? Should I unset it, and let it fallback to whatever the default value is? If so, how should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this in the following manner (though I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it).

First, I wanted to check the properties / contents of the variables `document` and `printDocument` (see my question to understand how they were initialized). I achieved this by doing:

```
    string tempConvert = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(document);
    dynamic docProperties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(tempConvert);

    MessageBox.Show(docProperties.ToString());

    string tmpProp = "";
    foreach (var iProp in printDocument.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        tmpProp += iProp.Name + ":" + iProp.GetValue(printDocument, null) + "\r\n";
    }

    MessageBox.Show(tmpProp.Trim());
```

The first one - `document` - held info on the dimensions of the document I wanted to print, while `printDocument` held various info regarding the current printer settings (paper orientation, margins, paper size, etc).

My next step was to extract the document dimensions from the `docProperties` variable, and I did this like this:

```
    string[] docDimensions = docProperties.PageSizes[0].ToString().Split(' ');
    char[] toTrim = { ' ', ',' };
    int docWidth = Convert.ToInt32(FormatNumber(docDimensions[0].Trim(toTrim)));
    int docHeight = Convert.ToInt32(FormatNumber(docDimensions[1].Trim(toTrim))) + 1;
```

Finally, I used the `docWidth` and `docHeight` to change the paper size, so that it would suit my needs (thermal POS printer, 80mm roll paper width):

```
    printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("customsize", Convert.ToInt32(1.4 * docWidth), Convert.ToInt32(1.4 * docHeight));
```

That 1.4 bit was something I settled on after a couple of series of trial and error.

Again, I'm aware that this is most likely **not** the best way to resolve the issue universally, but it did solve this specific problem.

Comment: @KJ Normally, I'd do it as you suggest, but the trouble is that I need to print out a QR code with it (local regulations and stuff like that). If I could work without it, I'd just print out a regulart *.txt and avoid *.pdf alltogether.